# Is there a way to apply a seperate template to different levels in Wayfinder?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, wayfinder, modx-getresources

I want to create a sub menu that uses divs and spans instead of uls, eg:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item
  <div>
    <span>Sub-item</span>
    <span>Sub-item</span>
    <span>Sub-item</span>
  </div>
 </li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to achieve this with Wayfinder (or getResources)?

Comment: Yep. Lots of different template parameters. It's all right there in the docs. https://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/wayfinder

Comment: @LIannotti ah, just so I make sure I understand, is `&innerTpl` and `&innerRowTpl ` the parameters I would need?